# How to align TextView around ImageView with fixed line of text

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Can you please tell me how to align `textView` around `imageview` like this

```
 _____
|     |
|_____| Some Dummy text,Some Dummy text,
Some Dummy text,Some Dummy text,S...more
```

I want to restrict my TextView only for 2 lines and at the end I will have one TextView or Button called more for more text which will open in pop up.

Is it possible to create something like this.?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. You need to use RelativeLayout under which you can place each of these views and align them as required.

Comment: I am using relative layout and I archives those 2 line text view against this but I am unable to create more view at text end.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:src="@drawable/pic7"
         android:text="image1" />

      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/text"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="Textview1" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, Please have a look:
http://gmariotti.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/snippet-align-textview-around-image.html